How awkward does 'He always gives me a plastic straw If I will order a milkshake' sound to your native ears?
The 'first conditional' consists of an 'if clause' and a 'main clause' that uses the modal verb 'will' to discuss future outcomes. However, using the words 'if' and 'will' in the same clause, as if it were a first conditional sentence, sounds odd. I believe the correct approach for this situation is to use the 'zero conditional', since it conveys the meaning that every time I order a milkshake, I end up receiving a plastic straw.
The only way this could be seen as a first conditional sentence is: 'He always gives me a plastic straw if I order a milkshake.' Additionally, I think using 'shall' instead of 'will' to imply a future plan could work, but I’m not completely sure.
Would such construction even be grammatically correct?

Neither will or shall belongs. Both of them would mark the speech as that of a nonnative speaker. The most natural would be to replace “if I will” by “when.”

Thank you! So, the only option for the sentence to be correct is to be in the zero conditional or use when instead of will right?

The problem with your sentence is that it should all be in the present tense.  It's not a conditional situation if it is something that always happens when (not if) you order a milk shake.

I am sorry, I cannot understand the (not if) part.

I mean don't use "if" here.

Thank you very much! I guess that's why it is called 'zero conditional'

I don't see any real difference between if and when here. The problem is order needs to be Simple Present (the word will is incorrect). Arguably when carries a slightly stronger implication that the speaker regularly does order milkshakes, but I think that's a bit fanciful. Effectively, He always gives me a plastic straw if I order a milkshake and He always gives me a plastic straw when I order a milkshake mean exactly the same to me. Changing when to whenever also makes next to no difference.

Thank you very much! This a very illustrative explenation.

I also don't think "zero conditional" and "first conditional" are useful terms (or indeed concepts) here. Syntactically, there's no difference between When you freeze water it becomes solid and If I freeze water it becomes solid and If I order a milkshake he gives me a straw.

He will always give me a plastic straw if I order a milkshake. OR He always gives me etc. That's the right sequence of tenses. will + verb, if + simple present. How can you not get that if you talk about first conditional?

@Lambie I wonder if I could change the order of the clauses so that the sentence reads: "If I order a milkshake, he will give me a plastic straw." I'm asking this because you mentioned the correct sequence of tenses. For the first conditional, the future tense comes first, followed by the simple present. However, in the sentence "He always gives me a plastic straw if I order a milkshake," both clauses use the simple present tense. In this case, the order doesn't matter.

This illustrates a zero conditional, where the order of the clauses does not matter.

By sequence I meant within one clause. The order of clauses doesn't matter at all. I just wasn't clear. :)

@Quique In the zero conditional, the main clause is in the simple present tense. The zero conditional: If I order a milkshake, he gives me a plastic straw. First Conditional: If I order a milkshake, he will give me a plastic straw. Because of. "will always, it's a zero conditional

Neither will nor shall belongs. Both of them would mark the speech as that of a nonnative speaker.
The most natural would be to replace “if I will” by “when.”
The always marks this sequence of events—my ordering followed by his giving—as frequent (or anyway more than merely occasional), which makes the if a bit odd.

Here are a variety of idiomatic ways of expressing the fact that he includes a plastic straw when serving a milkshake -- at least when you are the customer.

Whenever I order a milkshake he gives me a plastic straw.
If I order a milkshake he gives me a plastic straw.
When I order a milkshake he gives me a plastic straw.
He always gives me a plastic straw when I order a milkshake.

Let's say you say those things to me, and I reply that you're a liar,  that I happen to know the owner of the shop is against plastic straws and never uses them.   You reply:

OK, come with me then, if you don't believe me, and see with your own eyes. If I order a milkshake he will give me a plastic straw.

That is, the only time you'd  use will in the main clause following upon an if-clause is when the context clearly involves the future.
Similarly, you would use will  in the if-clause only if there is a clear future scenario:

If I will be manning the front-desk tomorrow, I cannot attend that meeting.


To my (British) eats, if I will means if I am willing to.
The implication here is that he wants me to order a milkshake, and he will reward me if I fall in with his wishes.
For that reason, shall is not possible here, any more than the purely temporal sense of the modal will.
As far as I am aware, any use of will in an if clause has that sense, and cannot be used merely for its temporal sense.

Thank you very much! As far as I know, the modal verb 'shall' is also used as an 'if am willing to' just like you said for the modal will, so the problem here is that the whole construction is a conditional construction which would render the mentioned use invalid.

But simply leaving out will is much more natural (meaning 'every time I order a milkshake').

No, @Quique, shall is not used to mean willing to. Apart from its weak "future" use, it can mean strongly intend to (for some speakers), and it gets used in technical documents to express a requirement. But it can't be used to mean willing.
